# Getting latest version from a Newline delimited list in BASH

Tags: bash

I am running a small curl command to retrieve the following information from a webpage.
I would like to receive from this output the "latest version" of whatever the damage file
in question is. Things to keep in mind are that there are RC numbers, that this is also
alread inside of a loop (code below) and that the the output might not always be in order.

Input

```
facter-1.7.5-rc1.dmg
facter-1.7.5-rc2.dmg
facter-1.7.5.dmg
facter-1.7.6.dmg
facter-2.0.1-rc1.dmg
facter-2.0.1-rc2.dmg
facter-2.0.1-rc3.dmg
facter-2.0.1-rc4.dmg
facter-2.0.1.dmg
facter-2.0.2.dmg
facter-2.1.0.dmg
facter-2.2.0.dmg
facter-2.3.0.dmg
```

Expected output

```
facter-2.3.0.dmg
```

Loop that is currently processing it

```
function get_latest()
{
  local url="$1"
  local name="$2"

  for pkg in $(wget -q "${url}" -O - |grep -o ">${name}.*dmg" |cut -c 2-); do 
    echo "${url}/${pkg}"; 
  done
}

FACTER_URL="$(get_latest 'http://downloads.puppetlabs.com/mac/' 'facter')"
echo $FACTER_URL ##http://downloads.puppetlabs.com/mac/facter-2.3.0.dmg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use make use of `sort -V` here:

```
sort -rV file | head -1
facter-2.3.0.dmg
```

As per `man sort`:

```
  -V, --version-sort
          natural sort of (version) numbers within text
```

**PS:** This will also take care of `rc` versions.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach (I use a proper XML/HTML parser) :

```
get_latest() {
  local url="$1"
  local name="$2"

  printf '%s\n' $(xmllint --html --xpath "//a/@href[contains(., '$2')]" $url) |
      sort -V |
      awk -F'"' 'END{print url$2}' url=$url
}

get_latest 'http://downloads.puppetlabs.com/mac/' 'facter'
```

Output :

```
http://downloads.puppetlabs.com/mac/facter-2.3.0.dmg
```

Note :

`xmllint` comes with `libxml2-utils` for `debian` and derivatives